# Android Dagger 2.11 Как внедрить Context

Tags: android, dagger2, di

Есть класс (например) AppPreferences, ему необходим Context приложения, но я получаю NullPointerException.

```
public class AppPreferences {
    @Inject // TODO context == null
    Context context; 

    private SharedPreferences mPref;

    public AppPreferences() {
        mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(AlmaApp.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Есть класс MyApp

```
public class MyApp extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .context(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

Есть AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder context(Context context);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MyApp app);
}
```

AppModule из уроков я не совсем понял

```
@Module(includes = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class})
public interface AppModule {
  // создать отдельный модуль ContextModule или добавить сразу сюда?
}
```

Т.е. я не знаю как правильно внедрить Context в AppPreferences. Интересует Dagger 2.11. Верно ли я понял что более ранние версии Dagger 2 использовали немного другой подход в архитектуре android приложений.

P.S. Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите литературу по Dagger 2.11 в которой поэтапно с пояснениями все объясняется. Во многих уроках многое опускается, что не касается Dagger 2, из за этого не совсем понимаю как все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ПОсмотрите вот это видео на русском: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HLV6bGKPc4, подробнее тут например: https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-the-new-dagger-android-module-9eb6075f1a46

У вас должно быть что-то вроде:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    Context provideContext(App application) {
        return application.getApplicationContext();
    }
```